# Python - Iterate file with row delimiter Timestamp

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a log file which I need to parse to json format. Issue is with parsing file with timestamp delimiter instead of new line.

Log File Format:

```
2021-10-26 10:24:17.048 [ERROR] The mapping failed to run for
worflow with name 'dummy'
2021-10-26 11:00:00.048 [INFO] Data parsed successfully
2021-10-26 11:00:00.048 [INFO] Data parsed successfully
```

As in the first line above, one record can go over multiple lines. I wish to populate it in one field

```
import json
i=1
result={}
with open(r"C:\Users\a1.txt","r") as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    r=line.split(' ')
    result[i]={'timestamp':r[0]+' '+r[1],'severity':r[2],'message':' '.join(r[3:])}
    i+=1
print(json.dumps(result))
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{"timestamp": "2021-10-26 10:24:17.048", "severity": "[ERROR]", "message": "The mapping failed to run for worflow with name 'dummy'"},  {"timestamp": "2021-10-26 11:00:00.048", "severity": "[INFO]", "message": "Data parsed successfully"},{"timestamp": "2021-10-26 11:00:00.048", "severity": "[INFO]", "message": "Data parsed successfully"}
```

**Current code output:**

```
{"1": {"timestamp": "2021-10-26 10:24:17.048", "severity": "[ERROR]", "message": "The mapping failed to run for \n"}, "2": {"timestamp": "worflow with", "severity": "name", "message": "'dummy'\n"}, "3": {"timestamp": "2021-10-26 11:00:00.048", "severity": "[INFO]", "message": "Data parsed successfully\n"}, "4": {"timestamp": "2021-10-26 11:00:00.048", "severity": "[INFO]", "message": "Data parsed successfully"}}
```

Comment: Does it really have a new-line/CR after `for`? Normally, I would expect it to be one line, regardless how long is the message.

Comment: Yes new line is indeed present in data